# Python Telegram bot. Ошибка: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Начинаю изучать телеграммбота, но столкнулся с ошибкой not callable. Может кто-нибудь направить?

```
import cnf
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot(cnf.TOKEN)
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Privet")
bot.polling()
```

Comment: Запустил у себя - все прекрасно работает. Надеюсь, что вы не забыли задать токен в своем коде, а просто не показываете его нам

Comment: Да, токен есть, с ним все хорошо, но почему-то мне выдает ошибку
Это все что в cnf
`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
TOKEN = "1083927659:AAG_ohz3DjDrzN2yiltJwQMccg8Fa558aLY"`

Comment: А зачем вы используете библиотеку cnf? Здесь можно обойтись и без нее

Comment: Да, это лишь для всех будущих констант, чтобы не вносить их в основной код, для удобства.
У меня все еще сильно ругается на строчку     `@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])`
Как в PyCharme так и в IDLE, пробывал на разных ботов и пересоздавать файлы, ничего не помогает. В чем могло бы быть дело? С питоном вот вот знакомлюсь

Comment: Попробуйте без модуля cnf, должно помочь. Либо есть шанс, что токен не рабочий. В противном случае, попробуйте создать нового бота с новым токеном. Насчет строки ничего сказать не могу, у меня ничего на нее не ругается

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
import cnf
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('ваш токен')
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Privet")
bot.polling()
```

То есть без cnf перед токеном